liquid does not touch the mesh
How to make the liquid touch the mesh?

Liquids work with a voxel system, so basically the edge of the container is in the middle of a voxel and the system is rounding inward. You can try to change the size/position of the domain a bit to get the voxel edges to line up with the container sides (easiest way is to make the domain exactly the inner size and position of the container), or knock up the resolution to get it closer, or maybe make the real collision object a smaller version of the container inside the visible one.

Does the screenshot show the correct solution to the problem?   screenshot
domain selected

I think so, yes.
